# Connection is not open at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.BeginBinaryImport Error when SaveAllAsync with PostgreSQLCopyHelper

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, bulkinsert, npgsql

I want to create a package to bulk insert to Postgresql in .NET Core.
I used PostgreSQLCopyHelper for this.

here create my PostgreSQLCopyHelper:

```
 private static PostgreSQLCopyHelper<T> CreateHelper<T>(string schemaName, string tableName)
        {
            var helper = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<T>(schemaName, "\"" + tableName + "\"");
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var type = prop.PropertyType;
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute)))
                    continue;

                switch (type)
                {
                    case Type intType when intType == typeof(int) || intType == typeof(int?):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapInteger("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (int?)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type stringType when stringType == typeof(string):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapText("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (string)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type dateType when dateType == typeof(DateTime) || dateType == typeof(DateTime?):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapTimeStamp("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (DateTime?)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type decimalType when decimalType == typeof(decimal) || decimalType == typeof(decimal?):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapMoney("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (decimal?)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type doubleType when doubleType == typeof(double) || doubleType == typeof(double?):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapDouble("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (double?)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type floatType when floatType == typeof(float) || floatType == typeof(float?):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapReal("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (float?)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                    case Type guidType when guidType == typeof(Guid):
                        {
                            helper = helper.MapUUID("\"" + prop.Name + "\"", x => (Guid)typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(x, null));
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            return helper;
        }

> `Blockquote`
```

And here SaveAll my PostgreSQLCopyHelper:

```
 public void BulkInsert(List<TType> list)
        {
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server =localhost; Database = demodb;  Port=5432; User Id=postgres;Password=a`12345;"))
            {
                var postgreSQLCopyHelper = CreateHelper<TType>($"{_schemaName}", $"{_tableName}");
                postgreSQLCopyHelper.SaveAll(connection, list);
                
            }
        }
```

And I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbHWv.png)

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you... haven't opened the connection?

Call `connection.Open()` before starting the COPY operation (or better yet, OpenAsync() if you can do async).

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved. Because there was no problem in other methods without using `connection.Open() ` , I didn't think it was a problem